# Referencing global variables in local scopes

Tags: javascript

I would like to know memory leak in the below mentioned code. Does JavaScript do automatic garbage collection.

```
var aGlobalObject = SomeGlobalObject; 
function myFunction() {
   var localVar = aGlobalObject;
}
```

Do I have to clear the memory as given below.

```
var aGlobalObject = SomeGlobalObject; 
function myFunction() {
   var localVar = aGlobalObject;
   localVar = null;// or delete localVar
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a memory leak in that code. The local variable references the same object as the global variable. When the function returns, the local variable is removed because nothing has a reference to it anymore. The object itself remains, because it's still referenced by the global variable. (*When I say "the local variable is removed": Technically, the [implicit] container the variable is in no longer has anything referencing it and is available for garbage collection; the actual collection may happen later.*)

Javascript does indeed have garbage collection. The `delete` keyword means something *totally* different in Javascript than it does in, say, C++. Javascript objects have properties. You can completely remove a property from an object using `delete`, e.g.:

```
var obj = {};   // Blank object
obj.foo = 5;    // `obj` now has a property called `foo`
obj.foo = null; // `obj` STILL has a property called `foo`; its value is just null now
delete obj.foo; // `obj` no longer has a property called `foo`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [JavaScript does garbage collection](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript%20garbage%20collection).